# Modifying an Arrayed Object

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, lattice

Let's say I wanted to array a cube around a cylinder like so:
[image]

I have also added a lattice on the main cube that has the array modifier on it.

Now if I adjust the lattice by moving down the bottom edge, I get this:

[image]

How can I make it so that the lattice modifies each arrayed cube the same way? and can someone explain why the cubes are not being displaced in the same manner as the main one? I am still fairly new to blender and learning as I go.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you swap the modifiers in the modifier stack (in the properties panel) around, so that the lattice comes before the array?

Comment: Oooh, I see. I need to pay attention to the order of modifiers then. I was thinking maybe it had something to do with the object rotation or something. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the modifiers is relevant, they get executed top to bottom.

After the array modifiers, the duplicated cubes are part of the new mesh, so the lattice modifier acts on the new geometry independent from their original position.

Move the lattice modifier above the array modifier.